# Struggling to get SSLCertificateSocketFactory to enforce "socket.relaxsslcheck yes" on android emulator

Tags: android-emulator

I am using self signed certificates for development and testing purposes. I have investigated various approaches to get android emulator to accept self signed certificates. Thus far I have found variations of the following approaches:

1. Providing your own security classes that will accept any certificate.
2. Create a keystore for your app that contains the self signed public key.
3. Setting property socket.relaxsslcheck to yes.

The first 2 options are very involved and introduces into your code a dependency on your environment, e.g. dev, test or prod.

Option 3 I like because the environment configuration drives behaviour, not unlike a web container that will provide the configured datasource to apps running in the container. A development environment will point to a development datasource etc. Unfortunately I am struggling to get it to work. I have tried the following:

- Using adb to set the property

  `adb shell setprop socket.relaxsslcheck yes`
- Using System.setProperty

  `System.setProperty("socket.relaxsslcheck","yes")`
- Tried to make change /system/build.prop and default.prop

The first option just gets ignored. From what I have read it seems setting the property will take effect after restarted. But the property seems to be volatile, it does not survive an emulator restart.

The `System.setProperty(...)` approach seems to be too late as the Factory has already been created. Because of above concern (dev environment specific code in code) I would prefer not to go this route, unless there is no alternative.

The last option is supposed to survive emulator restart, but I am unable to write to those files even after running `adb root`.

I am new to Android dev and would appreciated some guidance on what the best approach is and how to get it to work.

Comment: I have succeeded in setting the property at emulator startup time using "./emulator -avd <avd name> -prop socket.relaxsslcheck=true" but it is still ignored by SSLSocketCertificateFactory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have to exactly specify 'yes' with that option, i.e.:

```
-prop socket.relaxsslcheck=yes
```

The source code just compares the properties value against 'yes' (and does not bother to also test against equivalent values like 'true' or '1' ...)

Using the ADT bundle I set that option via

```
Run -> Debug Configurations... -> Android Application -> ProjectName -> Target
  -> Additional Emulator Command Line Options
```

After a restart of the emulator `SSLSocketCertificateFactory` works at advertised, i.e. it accepts all certificates. One can verify that via looking at the logs:

```
12-08 18:10:52.382: W/SSLCertificateSocketFactory(763): 
  *** BYPASSING SSL SECURITY CHECKS (socket.relaxsslcheck=yes) ***
```

I tested it with a self-created certificate - without that property set connecting fails with a certificate verification error, with that property set (or using `SSLCertificateSocketFactory.getInsecure()`) the TLS socket connects just fine.

Btw, `SSLSocketCertificateFactory` seems to be tricky to use at times - for example [I am struggling to get an actual instance from that very Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779404/how-to-get-an-sslcertificatesocketfactory-instance) - people posting workarounds that basically say: ignore that factory. Googling around some people even recommend [against](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-security-discuss/QXJMhV0b5Hw/1J6wUDXi0U0J) using that factory at all - but without giving much reasons.