# How to get an SSLCertificateSocketFactory instance?

Tags: android, sockets, ssl

Looking at the [SSLCertificateSocketFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/SSLCertificateSocketFactory.html) documentation I can't see how to use that factory to get such an instance.

I mean using the Constructor [is deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/SSLCertificateSocketFactory.html#SSLCertificateSocketFactory%28int%29). The recommended [`getDefault()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/SSLCertificateSocketFactory.html#getDefault%28int%29) just returns a `SocketFactory` or a `SSLSocketFactory` ...

But there is no method that returns a **SSLCertificateSocketFactory**.

I guess one can live with SSLSocketFactory for some use cases - but I am interested in using SSLCertificateSocketFactory features, like `setTrustManagers()`, e.g. for optionally using the fingerprint of a server certificate for verification.

Thus my question.

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly, I'm not exactly sure what SSLCertificateSocketFactory is here for, because, as you mention, the factory does not exactly what one expects. Sure, you could typecast your way through, but why would one want to do that.

Go for SSLContext.getInstance("TLS") -- or, if you only target API 9 and above, getDefault() -- and use SSLContext.init() to set the TrustManagers, like everyone else apparently does.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do, it isn't a good for everything solution.

A solution to trust everyone it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https), you can figure out what you need to modify.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Refer the link suggested by matheszabi

```
protected org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory createAdditionalCertsSSLSocketFactory() {
try {
    final KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");

    // the bks file we generated above
    final InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource( R.raw.mystore);  
    try {
        // don't forget to put the password used above in strings.xml/mystore_password
        ks.load(in, context.getString( R.string.mystore_password ).toCharArray());
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }

    return new AdditionalKeyStoresSSLSocketFactory(ks);

} catch( Exception e ) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
}
```